# Check whether value exists in column for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having a difficult time putting what I am trying to do into words so searching is also difficult.

Basically I am trying to look whether a certain value exists in a column, partitioned by group, and then propagate that value forward.

In this example I want to check whether a user has completed the tutorial and set a flag that carries forward.

```
pk | user | ... | activity
 1 |    A | ... |  "login"
 2 |    A | ... |  "started_tutorial"
 3 |    A | ... |  "completed_tutorial"
 4 |    A | ... |  "some other activity"
 5 |    A | ... |  "logout"
 5 |    B | ... |  "login"
 6 |    B | ... |  "logout"
```

I think this should be something like

```
select *,
    check(activity in ('completed_tutorial')) as completed_activity
    from tbl
```

but I don't think I can use `check` in a select statement and this would be a constant flag rather than set to true only after it has been found.

Example of what I am trying to get:

```
pk | user | ... | activity               | completed_tutorial
 1 |    A | ... |  "login"               |                 0
 2 |    A | ... |  "started_tutorial"    |                 0
 3 |    A | ... |  "completed_tutorial"  |                 1
 4 |    A | ... |  "some other activity" |                 1
 5 |    A | ... |  "logout"              |                 1
 5 |    B | ... |  "login"               |                 0
 6 |    B | ... |  "logout"              |                 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter SQL groups with the [`HAVING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP). For example, you can group your table by users and their activity, and then filter it to contain only those that have completed the tutorial:

```
SELECT user FROM tbl
GROUP BY user, activity
HAVING activity = 'completed_tutorial';
```

**EDIT:** After OP has edited their question, this is my new answer. Here, I assume that your table has a date field.

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(date >= (
    SELECT date FROM tbl WHERE activity = 'completed_tutorial'
    AND user = outertbl.user
), FALSE)
FROM tbl AS outertbl
ORDER BY date
```

Notice, that such query is essentially N² when unoptimised, so I would recommend instead to just get the data from the database and then process it in your program.

Comment: This is helpful but I don't want to filter/remove rows. Instead I want to have an indicator for each row to denote whether the activity has occurred or not.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about the speed of this, but what about the following solution?

```
SELECT
    user
    ,max(CASE
            WHEN activity = "completed_tutorial" THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS completed_tutorial
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY user
 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this

```
SELECT a.*, coalesce(b.completed, 0)
FROM tbl a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user, 1 completed 
           FROM tbl 
           WHERE user = a.user 
                 AND activity='completed_tutorial') b 
ON a.user = b.user AND b.pk >= a.pk
```

it assumes there is at most one row with `activity='completed_tutorial'` and that user identifies the "session". you'll have to add another field if a user can make more than one tutorial.

Comment: This looks really good. I'll keep playing with it to double check that it is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: So this seems to create an indicator for whether `activity` is "completed_tutorial" but does not propagate the indicator forward. :(

Comment: what do you mean by "propagate forward"? it will join all the records with its corresponding "completed_tutorial" if it exists.

Comment: if you look at rows 4 and 5 in my example you will see that the `completed_tutorial` indicator is positive because row 3 `activity = "completed_activity"`

Comment: ok, added a condition assuming pk is an autonumeric which gives the time sequence, so the rows after completed are completed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user FROM tbl
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN activity = 'completed_tutorial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

This will give you all the users who have completed the tutorial, at least once.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT user FROM tbl
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN activity = 'completed_tutorial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
This will give you all the users who have completed the tutorial, exactly once.