# How to check if value exists in each group (after group by)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume I have a subscriptions table :

```
uid  | subscription_type 
------------------------  
Alex | type1
Alex | type2
Alex | type3
Alex | type4
Ben  | type2
Ben  | type3
Ben  | type4
```

And want to select only the users that have more than 2 subscriptions but never subscribed with type 1

The expected result is selecting "Ben" only.

I easy can found the users that have more than 2 subscribes using:

```
SELECT uid
FROM subscribes
GROUP BY uid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

But how to check if in a group some value never exists?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `But how to check if in a group some value never exists?` maybe you need to add a where clause with a `NOT EXITS(..)` !

Comment: I tried this:
SELECT uid
FROM subscribes
GROUP BY cid,offer
HAVING COUNT(*)> 2 AND NOT EXISTS ( 
 SELECT uid, subscription_type
 FROM subscribes
 WHERE  subscription_type = 'renew')

But it's not working, returns empty table

Comment: You need to *couple* the uid in the subquery to that of the main query. Then it should work. Also: it should be in a `WHERE` clause, not in a having clause.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT uid 
FROM subscribes 
GROUP BY uid 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
   AND max( CASE "subscription_type"  WHEN 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Create Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE subscribes
(
uid NVARCHAR(MAX),
subscription_type NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Insert Values:

```
INSERT INTO subscribes
VALUES ('Alex', 'type1'), ('Alex', 'type2'), ('Alex', 'type3'), ('Alex', 'type4'),  ('Ben', 'type2'), ('Ben', 'type3'), ('Ben', 'type4')
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT uid
FROM subscribes
GROUP BY uid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
AND MAX(CASE subscription_type WHEN 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Output:

```
======
|uid |
------
|Ben |
======
```

Answer (score 6):

To check if something doesn't exist, use `NOT EXISTS(...)`:

```
SELECT uid
FROM subscribes su
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM subscribes nx
        WHERE nx.uid = su.uid AND nx.subscription_type = 'type1'
        )
GROUP BY uid HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a type exists in the predicate operation, then using the [`HAVING` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is your best bet as other answers have pointed out.

*But* if you don't want to filter the records, and instead want to see if a value is contained in a group in your projection operation, the having clause won't work in a select statement

To show whether a particular group contains a record (or not), you can combine a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to check each row with a [`MAX` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to evaluate all rows within a group, like this:

```sql
SELECT uid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN subscription_type = 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN subscription_type = 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN subscription_type = 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN subscription_type = 'type4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type4
FROM subscribes
GROUP BY uid
```

Which will return this:

| uid | type1 | type2 | type3 | type4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Ben | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

[**Demo in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f594e/6)

#### Further Reading

- [Check whether value exists in column for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28240119/1366033)
- [T-SQL Group By; Contains or IfAny](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7790057/1366033)