# Screening for data not present through multiple records for each case

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am relatively new to SQL. I have run into something though that has me completely stumped.

I have one table [Tab1], roughly like this:

```
IDNo  | FileType 
------------------------  
   1  | type1
   1  | type2
   1  | type3
   1  | type4
   2  | type2
   2  | type3
   2  | type4
   3  | type1
   3  | type3
   3  | type4
   4  | type2
   4  | type3
```

And then I have another table [Tab2] like this:

```
  Pno | Status
------------------------  
   1  | AC
   2  | CA
   3  | AC
   4  | AC
```

**I am needing to screen Tab2, to only display AC status records, while checking Tab1 to see what files are missing for each Pno.** This is the closest I've gotten.

```
SELECT Pno from Tab2 where Pno NOT IN (

SELECT DISTINCT t1.Pno FROM (SELECT IDNo, Filetype FROM Tab1 where Filetype LIKE 'Type1') As t1 ) AND Status = 'AC'
```

But, this doesn't make sure there aren't repeat records in Tab1 under IDNo. I've gone at this another couple ways, including this method ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784786/how-to-check-if-value-exists-in-each-group-after-group-by)) but it didn't work as it was returning false positives. This was my second stab, kind of taking what I got from research and modifying what I had.

```
SELECT Pno, Status 
from Tab2 
where Pno NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT t1.IDNo 
FROM (
    SELECT IDNo, FileType 
    FROM Tab1 
    where FileType LIKE 'Type 1') 
As t1 ) 
AND Status <> 'CA'
Order by Tab2.Pno
```

This time, I still got false positives.

Can anyone help on this?

So the output should be:

```
  Pno 
------- 
   4
```

As only PNo 1 and 3 are of Ac status and possess a Type1 File

Comment: Perhaps add a table showing us what the correct output would look like

Comment: Added at the bottom.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: The database is on RBDMS

Comment: RBDMS is an abbreviation. What is the name of the database product you use?

Comment: I'm sorry, my head stopped working a moment there. MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

IN the OP's comment below, the desired output is Status = 'AC' with no FileType = Type1.  While this does not match the desired output listed in the question, this is a query that would achieve that result:

```
Select Pno
From Tab2
Where Status = 'AC'
And Pno not in (Select IDNo
                From Tab1
                Where FileType= 'type1')
```

Looking at the given Tab1 and Tab2, the output should be: 4

Comment: Well, because what I need isn't where the Status = 'AC', it's where the Status = 'AC' and there are no Type1 forms. I'll try to make that clearer in my question.

Comment: @EF87, In your output, you have 1 and 3.  In Tab1, you have the records, 1, Type1 and 3,Type1.  From your comment above, I would have thought 1 and 3 should be excluded, and 4 should be included.  Please clarify and update your question.

Comment: Apologies, you're correct. This is why I should be more careful about posting things on little sleep. Question has been updated. Also, I and a guy I was working with found the answer. I will be posting it shortly.